# Html ValidationMessage not working since upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an update controller action that checks validation.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(InitialiseModel(model));
```

My view uses UIHelpers:

```
<%=Html.EditorForModel("MyModelTemplate") %>
```

I have a String property in my model called "Title" which has the attribute [Required]:

```
 [Required]
 [DisplayName("Resource title")]
 public string Title { get; set; }
```

The UI template for this property looks like this:

```
<%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired ? "*" : "" %>
<label for="<%=ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName %>">
    <%=ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName() %>
</label>
<input type="text" id="<%=ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName%>" 
 name="<%=ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName%>" value="<%=Model%>" />

<%= Html.ValidationMessage(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName, "*") %>
```

The problem is *ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired* is always false. And the validation message is never displayed. What am I missing?

Comment: Is it creating the validator span tags in the HTML source?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bug?

From:
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

Brad Wilson said in reply to Andrew...

I don't believe that [Required] sets IsRequired to be true today, which sounds like it's probably a bug. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jimmy, quite helpful, but I'm still confused about why the line <%=Html.ValidationMessage(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName, "*") %> is not displaying a validation error...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ajax.BeginForm or Html.BeginForm?  [I just read thi](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=4700)s which explained my problem and yours too if you're using Ajax.BeginForm..